# Need pronunciation feedback: What do you do?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

I need your feedback. Did I pronounce the question "What do you do?" good or not so good in American English? https://clyp.it/wnxeqwau

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm far from convinced ELL is the right place for this type of question. You should *listen* and *talk* to real live native speakers in natural contexts. Phonemic fragments taken in isolation are usually a poor reflection of actual speech, and this focus on "American pronunciation" also seems misplaced.

Comment: I did the listening. This is how I heard it in a movie. I just wanted to know if it's pronounced correctly. I was curious if "What do you" are really squeezed together in one sound. Some people pronounce it "whaddya" , but I also heard it with an "u" ending. There always need to be someone negative who can't refrain from commenting.

Comment: We've been here before, I think. You might want to check out [linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) if you want a better understanding of how pronunciation is "reduced" in natural speech.

Comment: There's not **one** correct way of pronouncing it... If you're being lazy, you might smash them all together but I wouldn't say that's the "correct" way.  In fact, if I was talking to a group of people and then decided to ask one person in particular what they do, I would likely emphasize the **you**... so "What do **you** do?"

Comment: It's pretty good.

Comment: Good, but slow it down 25%. At your present rapid clip, you'd get asked  "say what?" if you ventured below the Mason-Dixon line. You can also articulate and isolate the "what"  more than you're doing,  and then elide "d'ya do".

Comment: I concur with Snailboat. For the record, pretty much all intonational phrases are joined together as "one sound" as it were :)

Answer (score 1):

You pronounced it pretty much perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Sonds great. I think I hear a (slight) rise in tone moving into the end. This is not used in WH- questions. In fact, you can have a downward tone toward the end and it is still understood as a question. Yeah, the speed could be slowed down. But as you interact more with native speakers, you can get it even better.